# Улучшение страницы справки «Что делать, когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Хотел бы давать новичкам ссылку на инструкцию, что делать с ответами. Но заметил, что предпочитаю заменять её более простыми фразами.

Предлагаю переписать текст, чтобы новичок наверняка понял, чего от него ждут и какими возможностями он обладает.

- [Страница справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
- [Оригинал на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
- [FAQ How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/330339)

Comment: Сделал ваш ответ «общим», чтобы другие участники смогли добавить что–либо, при необходимости.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?

#### Используйте голосование

Если ваша репутация позволяет, то [голосуйте за](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) полезные, аргументированные ответы и [против](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) бесполезных или поверхностных. Другие участники тоже могут голосовать за ответы на ваш вопрос или против них.

Если голосуете «против», объясните причину в комментарии к ответу. Это не обязательно, но, возможно, автор доработает ответ и ваше мнение изменится. Тогда вы сможете проголосовать повторно.

#### Уточните ответ, поясните вопрос

Если ответ помог лишь частично, напишите об этом в комментарии к ответу.

Если ответом трудно воспользоваться, задайте уточняющие вопросы автору ответа в комментариях.

Если автор ответа неправильно понял задачу, объясните отличия или дополните ваш исходный вопрос новыми подробностями.

#### Отметьте ответ как решение

Вы можете отметить ответ правильным, если он лучше всего решает именно вашу задачу. Ваше мнение не обязано совпадать с голосами других участников.

Не торопитесь принимать первый полученный ответ. Дождитесь [хорошего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Для того, чтобы отметить вопрос принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ [отмечен как решение вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.

#### Не благодарите автора ответа в комментариях

Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.

И продолжайте задавать вопросы, пишите полезные ответы. Ваш вклад в общую базу знаний — лучшая благодарность!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky У меня два предложения. 1) Заменить заголовок статьи на тот, что в этом ответе. `Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?` похоже на кальку с английского. Он состоит из двух предложений вместо одного, а слова `когда` и `кто-то` создают лишний шум. Поэтому заголовок труднее читать и сложнее узнавать в списке статей. 2) Выделить подзаголовки жирным шрифтом. Сейчас их трудно отличить от основного текста, и структура статьи становится невидимой. Если жирным нельзя, то предлагаю вернуть нумерацию подзаголовков. Что скажете?

Comment: Отличное предложение! Единственное, я бы чуть-чуть переформулировал, например, `Как реагировать на ответы в моем вопросе?`. Что скажите?

Comment: Мне кажется, статья из раздела помощи похожа на плакат. Человек, попав в беду, должен быстро заметить инструкцию к спасению. Поэтому `Что делать при пожаре` мне нравится больше, чем `Как реагировать на пожар в моей квартире` :) А идеалом было бы `При пожаре звони 01`.

Comment: Обновил публикацию.